# ¿Por qué no puedo identificar espacios en blanco en un array de caracteres?

Tags: array, c, string

Tengo que hacer una función que elimine los espacios en blanco del final de un `string`.

La función es la siguiente

```
void user_trimCapitalizeName(User *object){}
```

Para lo que nos ocupa, `User` es un `struct` tal que:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *name;
} tUser;
```

Bien, pues mi idea es la siguiente: 
Creo un vector que copie el string del objecto que se le pasa a la función y además obtengo su longitud.

```
char *name = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(object->name));
name = strcpy(name, object->name);
```

Ahora me creo unas funciones auxiliares para medir y obtener datos y recorrer el string desde el final hasta que encuentre algun carácter, es decir, mientras que lo que encuentre sean carácteres en blanco.

```
int finalBlankSpaces = 0;
int nameLength = strlen(name);
int lastChar = nameLength-1;

while (name[nameLength] == ' ')
{    
    finalBlankSpaces++;
    nameLength--;
}
    lastChar = nameLength;
```

Estos datos los utilizaré posteriormente para hacer un substring y con ello "eliminar" los carácteres vacíos.

El problema es que para un nombre cualquiera, por ejemplo `"Pedro Duque   "` directamente ni entra dentro del bucle. El caso es que he hecho otra función igual pero para eliminar los carácteres de antes del nombre y sí funciona.
¿Por qué al revés no?

Comment: No me interesa saber cuantos espacios en blanco hay, sino cuantos espacios en blanco hay desde el último carácter (no blanco) hasta el fin ( '\0' )

Comment: Borré el comentario, había entendido mal. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí:

```
int nameLength = strlen(name);
```

Estás haciendo que `nameLength` almacene el índice del caracter que finaliza la cadena `\0`. Así:

```
strlen("HOLA") = 4; // H O L A \0
                    // 0 1 2 3 4
```

Y `'\0' != ' '`, luego el `while` no se ejecutará nunca.

Lo que tienes que hacer es restar 1 a lo devuelto por `strlen`:

```
int nameLength = strlen(name) - 1;
```